# Change the insecure default to restricting scope to LAN, for adding exceptions to the windows 7 firewall?

Tags: windows-7, firewall

My network is generally set to Home or Work, i'm not commenting here on Public.

I understand that with Home or Work, the Private firewall profile is used.

I have noticed that with the Windows 7 Firewall,  when a program requests an exception, and I click OK, then the default is that it allows any "remote"(as in- outside of my LAN)  IP to make an incoming connection to that program.

To change that i'd have to go to the rule..properties..scope..remote IP..those IP addresses.. and enter my subnet.

Is it possible to make that the default?